# Find matched text in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of input string in the following (simplified) format:

```
"Hello my name is Dan"
"Hey my name is Tony"
"Hey|Hello|Hi my name is _"
```

I'm trying to write a regular expression to extract the name from the previous examples, but I'm stuck on how to do it.

I currently have

```
import re
r = re.search("(Hello|Hey|Hi) my name is .+")
```

How do I actually get the captured name?

Comment: try this `re.search("my name is ([^ ]+)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually not too far off. You're missing the supplied text to the regex, but I'm guessing you actually want to compile one to use later

```
import re
r = re.compile("(Hello|Hey|Hi) my name is (.+)")
```

... later

```
match = r.search(text)
if match:
    name = match.groups()[1]
```

What's going on here is that everything surrounded by parens is treated as a captured group. You can refer to it later if there's a match. You can also have named matches by using `(?P<name>PATTERN)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
r = re.search("(?:Hello|Hey|Hi) my name is (\w+)", "Hello my name is Tony")
print r.groups()[0]
```

prints `Tony`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `(\w+)` match grouping.

But if "my name is" is expected to be in your strings, why not to use something alike
`r.split('my name is ', 1)[1].split(' ', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Use **groups** to retrieve the part of your regex match. Here is an improved variant of your codelet:

```
import re
str = "Hello my name is Dan"
r = re.search("(Hello|Hey|Hi) my name is (.+)", str)
name = r.group(2)
```

I added parenthesis around (.+) so that they can be referred by the search object. group(0) is the complete matched string. group(1) is the first group - either of Hello, Hey or Hi. group(2) is the name.